# Another Jquery form validation issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to implement a form validation using jquery, but so far am not able to get it working. I have been reading several of the other questions, but none seem to help me on my way.
I am using the Jquery validation plugin http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/
To my understanding the basic idea is to give your form an ID, and add class="required" to the specific input fields, but so far nothing has been happening, and it happily posts my form.

my script is:

```
<script>
           $(document).ready(function(){
               $("#validate").validate();
               });
</script>
```

the form looks like this:

```
<form action="" id="validate"  method="post">
   <?do
    {
    ++$i; ?>
    <button type="button" class="togbut" href="#<?echo $i;?>">Lijst voor <?echo $_SESSION['leerlingen'][$i];?> invullen</button> <br>
    <div id="<?echo $i;?>" style="display:none"> <?
    echo $_SESSION['leerlingen'][$i];  ?>




          <fieldset>
                    <input type='hidden' name='ingevuld' id='ingevuld' value='1'/>
                    <legend>A. Leerprestaties:</legend>
                               <label>de prestaties blijven achter bij de capaciteiten</label>
                               <div><input type="radio" class="required" name="pr_ach_lp13<?echo ++$counter;?>" value="1"></div>
                               <div><input type="radio" class="required" name="pr_ach_lp13<?echo $counter;?>" value="2"></div>
                               <div><input type="radio" class="required" name="pr_ach_lp13<?echo $counter;?>" value="3"></div>
                               <div><input type="radio" class="required" name="pr_ach_lp13<?echo $counter;?>" value="4"></div>
                               <div><input type="radio" class="required" name="pr_ach_lp13<?echo $counter;?>" value="5"></div>
         </fieldset>
    </div>

 <?
    }  while($i<$_SESSION['num_rows']);?>
       <input id="submit" type="submit" value="opslaan">
</form>
```

could somebody please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your submit button is outside hour form. Ar you sure you submit your form?

Comment: sorry, that was a miss-type, it is actually inside the form. I've corrected it in the question

Comment: How about calling: `$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#validate").validate();
});`

Comment: Is your JS code mistyped? You must be getting JS error for this.

Comment: @Dmonix what do you mean?
@ Floremin I am not receiving any error at all, It's simply showing me the variables it's posted (that's in a php part)

Comment: @Jeroen try this JS code instead the one you have.

Comment: @Dmonix I have tried. still posting normally and no error message

Comment: Check if your html code is valid. You open div here `<div id="<?echo $i;?>" style="display:none">` and I don't see closing tag.

Comment: sorry, this was fine in the file, but I missed it while copying

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem seems to be that you have written your JavaScript in a way that is invalid.

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#validate").validate();//The instantion of form validator ends here
          onsubmit: true,
          onkeyup: false,
          onfocusout: false,
          onclick: false
          //The options above appear as though they should be part of an object
          //However they are free-floating and not contained in curly braces
          //Nor are they submitted to validate() as a parameter; since they are
          //technically outside the call to validate()
          });
```

Dmonix is suggesting you try calling the validate without that extra stuff.  Like this:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#validate").validate();
        });
```

And see if that works

Comment: Additionally; if the script you posted is verbatim then you need to add type="text/javascript" as an attribute to the text tag for it to be executed properly  Like so:  <script type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: In the extra comments you'll find that I had already changed this. But now I have also updated it in the original question. sorry for the confusion.
script type should no longer be necessary with html5, but I have changed it nonetheless, doesn't make a difference.

Comment: The default validation seems to just check that a value is set; perhaps since the radio buttons that you are validating all have values they are passing automatically.  Are you instead wanting to validate that at least one radio button is checked?

Comment: I realized I had made another studip error in the <script src=> part of the code. Now when I have 5 required classes on the radio buttons, it works fine. If you have a nicer way of requiring that one of the radio buttons is checked, I would be very much open to that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your suggestions I have found the problem. Since I wasn't getting any error messages, I thought it should be in the calling of the javascript sources. I have found I missed a closing tag for the script source, so it didn't find the plugin. Sorry for wasting your time, and thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Use firebug for debuging JS errors. You would see errors in console when you call undefined functions.